# How to link multiple checking accounts with 1 other checking account

Tags: united-states, checking-account

I have multiple bank accounts and I am trying to transfer money between them. Two of the accounts (A&B) are with the same bank and I am trying to transfer money to another account (C) which is with a credit union.

My bank lets me add the credit union (C) as an external account to my bank account A. However, when I try to add the account (C) to the bank account (B) it stops with an error message because I cannot link the same account (C) with (A) & (B). Is this limit coming from my bank where I have the bank account A & B or is this issue coming from the credit union (C)?

Can I solve this problem by opening an account (D) at another bank and closing A or B? These are all personal accounts and I would like to keep my finances separate. I would like to avoid writing myself checks. Unfortunately services like Zelle are not available with the credit union.

Comment: Can you transfer from B to A? It's one additional step but if you can transfer from B to A and A to C then you can effectively transfer from B to C. I doubt anyone where would know what is preventing the direct link - have you asked both banks?

Comment: I called both banks and was there in person. I would like to avoid transferring A->B->C as there are daily limits and I would need to stretch these movements out over multiple days. Technically it **is** possible but I would like to have it easier.

Comment: Bank office reps tend to have no more than a basic understanding of online features.  Sometimes you have to speak to tech support to resolve such issues.  If they can't resolve the A-B-C issue then closing (A) or (B) and opening (D) should resolve this.  You might consider opening (D) first and establishing the link to (C) and either (A) or (B).  Once achieved, then close out (A) or (B) and that one would be the one without the new link to (D).

Comment: What do you mean by "link"?  Is it just listing the account as a funds transfer destination, or are you setting up e.g. overdraft protection?  In the former case, the banks I've worked with maintain a list of external accounts per online login, not per account.  So all I have to do in your circumstance is open the transfer form, pick C as the destination and then both A and B are available as source accounts.

Comment: Echo Ben Voigt... in the UK, at least, the only "linking of accounts" I've heard of is essentially done by a bank itself if you have two or more accounts with them... if you go overdrawn on one, they reserve the right to take money from another account to cover it (not sure how often it might be used). For making payments (e.g. online or from a mobile banking app) you just need to add a "payee" and you can have as many of those as you want (or, at least, it's certainly not a small limit on numbers).

Comment: @Ben Voigt - In the U.S. you can "link" (aka connect) external accounts so that transfers can be made between them.  They can be one way links (A to B) or two way links (A to B and B to A).  Some require initial trial deposits by the bank.  Others require an application form.  Internally, links aren't necessary since you can transfer from any account to another.

Comment: @BobBaerker: But that's not a link between two deposit accounts, it's a link between a user login and an external deposit account.  (With joint accounts, my experience has been that an external account can be accessible to just whichever one of the acccountholders configured it)

Answer (score 1):

The limit is coming from the bank where you have account A and B

Opening account in different banks will definitely solve this.

There may be other banks that support A to B and A to C, with A and B in same bank. You may have to shop around.

Comment: I have opened an account at a different bank and will try this out. As soon as I have everything set up, I will report back.